# What is the name for the composition of a functor with a natural transformation?

Tags: ct.category-theory

In the second half of the section "[Operations with Natural Transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_transformation#Operations_with_natural_transformations)" of the wikipedia article on natural transformations, they define the operation taking a natural tranformation $\eta:F\to G$ in the functor category $Cat(C,D)$ and functor $H:D\to E$ which produces a new natural transformation $(H\circ F)\to (H\circ G)$ in $Cat(C,E)$ by applying the functor to every coordinate of the original natural transformation.  This operation frequently comes up in the definition of an adjunction.

Does this operation have a name?  It's not the "Godement multiplication", but might be related to it.

Is there an agreed-upon symbol for this operation, other than juxtaposition?

*(Minor rant: I think that using juxtaposition for this operation is a horribly cruel thing to do to people learning category theory.  Juxtaposition is already used for composition of morphisms -- and therefore for composition of functors-with-functors and naturaltransformations-with-naturaltransformations, since they too are the morphisms in $Cat$ and functor categories, respectively.  Recycling juxtaposition yet again for this (non-associative!) operation on functors and natural transformations is just asking for trouble.)*

Comment: This operation *is* associative.

Comment: @Toby, associativity is generally considered to be a property of binary operations whose arguments are of the same sort, so (a*b)*c=a*(b*c) is a well-sorted equation.  However, in this case, the arguments are of different sorts (one is a functor, one is a natural transformation).  What extension of the usual meaning of associativity do you have in mind here?

Comment: The definition of associativity I usually use in this case is "you can write a string of symbols without ambiguity". E.g. I might say that vector-space scalar multiplication is associative because if I see a*b*v it doesn't matter whether I interpret that as two scalar multiplications or scalar multiplication by a product.

Comment: Isn't associativity just an algebra for the non-empty list monad?

Comment: Adam, this is ancient history I realize, but Toby might have had in mind the associativity of the horizontal composition of three (horizontally composable) 2-cells where the two on the ends are identities $1_F$ , $1_H$ of 1-cells $F, H$.

Comment: Just to amplify Todd Trimble's explanation, for readers new to this: whiskering can usefully be seen as an instance of a composition in an associative _one-sorted_ partial algebra. The only sort there is "2-cell". In a sense, no separate name and concept is logically necessary. The fact that in usual occurrences of whiskering one of the two things composed is not a 2-cell is overcome by conceiving of a functor $F$ as the identity arrow $1_F$.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's called "whiskering" -- the 1-cells/functors composed on either side of the 2-cell/transformation look like "whiskers". See for example page 24 of [this paper](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/2rep.pdf). This terminology is pretty widespread in the categorical community.